# Как найти элемент во вложенных объектах массивов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть объект

```
const columnsForWidgets = {
        firstCol: {
            name: 'firstCol',
            items: ComponentsWidgets.ComponentsArr,
        },
        secCol: {
            name: 'secCol',
            items: ComponentsWidgets.ComponentsArr2,
        },

        thirdCol: {
            name: 'thirdCol',
            items: ComponentsWidgets.ComponentsArr3,
        },
        fourthCol: {
            name: 'fourthCol',
            items: ComponentsWidgets.ComponentsArr4,
        },
    };
```

В ключе items лежит еще массив типа

```
[
    {
      id: 'MttrWidget',
      show: true,
      comp: () => <MttrWidget />,
    },
    {
      id: 'BotCount',
      show: true,
      comp: () => <BotCount />,
    },
]
```

Они отрисовывают у меня виджеты на странице. Как добраться и изменить show на false в состоянии ? т.к они отрисовываются только если show true

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю есть и более изящные решения.

По быстрому придумал что-то такое

```
const keysObj = Object.keys(columnsForWidgets);

const result = keysObj.map(key => {
    const column = columnsForWidgets[key];
    const items = column.items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        show: true
    }))
    
    return {
        ...column,
        items
    }
})
```

[пример](https://codepen.io/grad/pen/NWpgjOo?editors=0012)

Comment: Спасибо большое, взял на заметку )